# Youtube API - Video Category ID assignables

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i would like to ask a question regarding the difference between "assignable": true and "assignable":false. There are some videoCategory IDs that are marked as "assignable":false and can't be pulled via the API call.

Could you advice on this as there are some videoCategories that are key to our search. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories#snippet.assignable), `assignable` is true if and only if the respective category is actually attributable (*assignable*) to any video's meta data.

In other words, one can call for endpoints [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) or [`Videos.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) setting (*assigning*) `snippet.categoryId` if and only if that category ID identifies a video category that has its property `assignable` set to true.